# Логика работы SASS SCSS и LESS?

Tags: sass, scss, less

Хочу понять в теории, как работают css препроцессоры SASS SCSS и LESS.

1. Браузер не читает напрямую данные из .sass (например) файла, нужно вначале скомпилировать .sass > .css?
2. Т.е. получается, что .sass файлы являются что-то вроде 'базовой' библиотеки стилей, из которой потом 'лепится' уже готовый набор .css файлов?

Comment: 1.) Да; 2.) Нет.

Comment: @VladSpirin почему нет, если первое да? из созданного .sass создаем .css ...

Comment: Это метаязык на основе CSS, а не библиотека. Хотя, с какого угла ещё посмотреть...

Comment: @VladSpirin я раньше на Less работал, но он как-то затухает, так что решил дальше на Sass работать, он сейчас повсеместно используется.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин про LESS, я писал, просто удалил. Согласен с вами, насчет его заката. SASS же наоборот, куда не зайди, любой плагин, фреймворк - он есть. Мне Stylus в последнее время приглянулся из-за родства с JS )

Comment: @VladSpirin хотел бы с вами пообщаться насчёт Stylus, в чате или по мессанджеру.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Давайте завтра, или в субботу. Я через 10 мин убегаю на работу. Напомните мне через комментарий, где-либо и спишемся... Или я вам постараюсь напомнить. Я тут каждый день. У меня "фанатик" будет через 5 дней )

Comment: @VladSpirin в мессанджер добавляйтесь, у меня в профиле, тогда точно не забудем

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Браузер не читает напрямую данные из .sass (например) файла, нужно вначале скомпилировать .sass > .css?

Браузер может работать только с CSS и для этого sass компилируется в CSS

> Т.е. получается, что .sass файлы являются что-то вроде 'базовой' библиотеки стилей, из которой потом 'лепится' уже готовый набор .css файлов?

sass это не "базовая библиотека" она сама по себе не содержит никаких стилей, sass это другой формат стилей и после компиляции получается обычный css который уже используется браузером. sass даёт большие возможностей, часто облегчает вёрстку и делает стили лучше читаемыми для разработчика.

Примерно такая же ситуация и с LESS.